Leer Respuesta Array XML de SOAP con PHP
Mi duda es cómo obtener la información de una respuesta XML que contiene Array.
Lo que he logrado es cargar el xml y mostrar su contenido, les comparto el código con la respuesta xml, agradezco su ayuda para resolver esta duda.
<?php
$result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:DatosResponse soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://ep.ws.prueba.nombres.comp.gob.gt\">
            <obtenerDatos soapenc:arrayType=\"soapenc:string[][3]\" xsi:type=\"soapenc:Array\" xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">
                <obtenerDatos soapenc:arrayType=\"soapenc:string[5]\" xsi:type=\"soapenc:Array\">
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">Juan</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">Lopez</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">20 años</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">100.00</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">Rojo</obtenerDatos>
                </obtenerDatos>
                <obtenerDatos soapenc:arrayType=\"soapenc:string[5]\" xsi:type=\"soapenc:Array\">
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">Pedro</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">Padilla</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">18 años</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">300.00</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">Azul</obtenerDatos>
                </obtenerDatos>
                <obtenerDatos soapenc:arrayType=\"soapenc:string[5]\" xsi:type=\"soapenc:Array\">
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">Sara</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">Fernandez</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">23 años</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">200.00</obtenerDatos>
                    <obtenerDatos xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">Verde</obtenerDatos>
                </obtenerDatos>
            </obtenerDatos>
        </ns1:DatosResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
";

$result = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $result);
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
var_dump($doc);


SimpleXMLElement te crea objetos debidamente estructurados. Para mostrarlos en PHP sólo tienes que convertirlos en array en este caso.
Por ejemplo:
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

# Array para convertir los objetos
$data = [];

foreach ( $doc->soapenvBody->ns1DatosResponse->obtenerDatos->obtenerDatos as $item ) 
{
        $data[]=(array) $item;
}

# Lectura de los datos para mostrarlos
foreach ($data as $person){
    foreach ($person['obtenerDatos'] as $v) 
    {
        echo $v,PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '---',PHP_EOL;
}

Salida:
Juan
Lopez
20 años
100.00
Rojo
---
Pedro
Padilla
18 años
300.00
Azul
---
Sara
Fernandez
23 años
200.00
Verde


EDICIÓN
Si quieres una salida diferente, por ejemplo,  mostrando al lado de cada dato el nombre de columna, tendrías dos formas de hacerlo.
Solución A
# Array para convertir los objetos
$data = [];
# Array para asignar los nombres de columnas
$columns=['nombre','apellido','edad','precio','color'];

foreach ( $doc->soapenvBody->ns1DatosResponse->obtenerDatos->obtenerDatos as $item ) 
{
    $data[]=(array) $item;
}

# Lectura de los datos para mostrarlos
foreach ($data as $person){
    foreach ($person['obtenerDatos'] as $k=>$v) 
    {
        printf("%-9s %s %s%s",$columns[$k],':',$v,PHP_EOL);
    }
    echo '---',PHP_EOL;
}

Solución B
O bien lo siguiente, en caso de querer tener como resultado final un array asociativo, donde cada dato se asigna a un nombre de columna:
# Array para convertir los objetos
$data = [];
# Array para asignar los nombres de columnas
$columns=['nombre','apellido','edad','precio','color'];

foreach ( $doc->soapenvBody->ns1DatosResponse->obtenerDatos->obtenerDatos as $item ) 
{
    $tmp=(array) $item;
    $data[] = array_combine($columns,$tmp['obtenerDatos']);
}

# Lectura de los datos para mostrarlos
foreach ($data as $person){
    foreach ($person as $k=>$v) 
    {
        printf("%-9s %s %s\n",$k,':',$v);
    }
    echo '---',PHP_EOL;
}

En ambos casos, la salida es la misma. Si sólo necesitas mostrar los datos en este contexto asociados a un nombre de columna, te recomiendo la Solución A, si necesitas pasar los datos a otra parte de forma asociativa, te recomiendo la Solución B.
Salida:
nombre    : Juan
apellido  : Lopez
edad      : 20 años
precio    : 100.00
color     : Rojo
---
nombre    : Pedro
apellido  : Padilla
edad      : 18 años
precio    : 300.00
color     : Azul
---
nombre    : Sara
apellido  : Fernandez
edad      : 23 años
precio    : 200.00
color     : Verde
---


Gracias @A. Cedano, funciono perfectamente.
Me surge una duda, para almacenar cada valor en su respectiva variable utilice condiciones if con la clave del elemento , es ideal utilizar estas o existe una mejor manera ??.  Dejo una demo de lo realizado DEMO

@KevinViken el código que muestras no aporta nada nuevo, en el sentido de que la salida es exactamente la misma que la indicada en mi respuesta. La diferencia con respecto a tu código es que creas variables innecesariamente, posiblemente recargando la memoria, para obtener una salida idéntica pero sin declarar variables. Otra cosa es que quieras crear un array asociativo, por ejemplo si te interesa mostrar al lado del dato el nombre de la columna, en cuyo caso puedes optar por las soluciones propuestas en la edición de la respuesta.

Gracias por la explicación @A. Cedano, me ha quedado más claro lo que debo realizar, muy agradecido por la ayuda y por compartir tus conocimientos, saludos.
